# SOH (\001) Fastload Delimiter

Tags: teradata

I'm trying to set the delimiter in a Fastload to \001 with no success.

Anybody know if this is possible?

```
SET record vartext "\001";
```

Comment: '\001' are four characters, but you probably want the ASCII character hex 1. This is not possible, the only allowed control character is TAB. VarText is supposed to be readable text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.

Teradata Fastload Reference, Chapter 3: Teradata Fasload Commands, Section 'SET RECORD'

> The delimiter can be a single or multi-character sequence (or string) 
>   ...
>   No control character other than a tab character can be used in a
>   delimiter.